# Why does my code cause a Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I run the following code, it shows "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Could you help me figure out the mistake I made？

```
#include <stdio.h>

int str_len(char *s);

int main()
{

    int m;
    char a[] = "Hello, world";
    char *pa;
    *pa = a[0];
    m = str_len(pa);
    printf("The length of the string is %d.\n", m);
    return 0;

}

int str_len(char *s)
{

    int n;
    for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
            n++;
    return n;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Error in code*: Assigning a character byte to a pointer. Technically it's ok, but the pointer does not contain a valid address.
The error carries on and str_len receives that character thinking it is a byte. Trying to access that invalid address may cause the Segmentation Fault.
**pa** char pointer is not initialized. Hence, `*pa = a[0]` is like trying to say `address_memory_for_pointers = a[0]`.
Try running:

```
int m;
char a[] = "Hello, world";
char *pa = a;
m = str_len(pa);
printf("The length of the string is %d.\n", m);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using index with array name will always refer to address of particular element at that index.

`*pa = a[0];` this will assign the `pa` to address of first element of array `a`, not the address of whole array.  You should assign `*pa = a; or  *pa = &a;`  if you are intended to make `pa` to point the whole array.